# SOAP C++ client

Tags: c++, xml, web-services, soap

I am assigned a task to retrieve information from a web service.
I have given a WSDL file and Thats it. My application is written in C++.
I have to extract some information from the response xml and create c++ instances. This process have to be done every iteration of my application execution.

{The web service gives current information about the location of vehicles on the road for example. My application needs to retrieve these information and draw that in the user interface. }

I have tried create mock request and response xml messages using SoapUI. Now I don’t know how to proceed further.

How can I send the request xml file to the web service from my application? How can I retrieve the responses? Is there any c++ standard library which support this task?

Any links, example program, tutorials would be really helpful.

Comment: _"Is there any c++ standard library which support this task?"_ No there isn't. You may lookup GSoap, if it fits for your needs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1413395/πάντα-ῥεῖ Thanks for the response. Is it open source ?

Comment: Yes, but there are commercial licenses available: https://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html

Comment: Your question is _offf-topic_ at Stack Overflow BTW. Read section #4 in this [Help Center article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: May I know why it is off-topic? I just read the help centre article you have linked. This question did not comply with the statement they indicated as off-topic.

Comment: _"Any links, example program, tutorials would be really helpful."_ You are asking for 3rd party resources, which is _off-topic_.

Comment: Thank you πάντα ῥεῖ  for pointing out my mistake.